# App launched via widget is closed via phone's back button which is taking to the app's activity which is launched via shortcut

Tags: android, service, android-widget, android-camera, onpause

I have an issue with the closing and restarting of my application. I have a `widget` on homescreen and also I created a `shortcut` for the app on homescreen. I am entering the app via shortcut and closing it in `Activity B` by pressing phone's home button. Now I launch the app via widget and pass through `Activity A` -> `Activity B` -> `Activity C`, then I come back to exit the app via phone's back button which goes like from `Activity C` -> `Activity B` -> `Activity A`. In `Activity A`, when I click back button it should close the app, but inspite of this it's showing the Activity B which is running in background that I launched by app shortcut.

I tried by killing the app in `onPause()`, it works fine. But then I have a `Camera` functionality, so as soon as I click a picture and click on save, it exits the app. I think on moving back to the activity from phone's Camera it goes into `onPause()` which is causing the app to exit.

Can anyone provide a solution for this.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of killing the app in onPause start the activity from shortcut or widget using intent flag :

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or 
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Please refer : [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)